# Access 64bit runtime with 32bit office

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have upgraded my access app to 64bit and I am in the process of updating client pcs to 64bit runtime.  I have updated dozens of pcs with 32bit office by using a different version of 64bit runtime (for instance, 2016 64bit runtime with 2013 32bit office, and 2013 64bit runtime with 2016 32bit office).  However, while updating a client today none of their pcs will allow the update.  They have office 2013 standard (32bit) and trying both 2016 64bit and 365 64bit access runtime fails with the error below.  What could be different with these pcs?  This is happening on both Windows 7 and Windows 10 pcs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - there was some sort of an error on the install of office 2013 (whenever it was installed).  The solution was to start the office 2013 setup again, and cancel at the first prompt (no need to uninstall first).  This fixed the error and allowed 2016 64bit access runtime to be installed.

Microsoft article explaining the above solution is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ar-sa/office/troubleshoot/error-messages/error-25090-starting-office-program)